# Unknown keyword `smtp-auth' when using --set=smtp-auth=login

Tags: shell-script, sendmail, mailx

I use a bash script to make some process, then send me a mail report. This works fine when I use a local postfix configuration, but this not works with smtp auth and I got the error «smtp-auth unknown».

This is the way I used to send mail (succesfully) :

```
tmp_file_headers=`mktemp`
tmp_file_body=`mktemp`

echo "The body" >> $tmp_file_body
echo "From: $from" >> $tmp_file_headers
echo "To: $to" >> $tmp_file_headers
echo "Subject: $subject" >> $tmp_file_headers
echo "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" >> $tmp_file_headers
mail_content="$(cat $tmp_file_headers $tmp_body)"
echo "$mail_content" | /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

This is the command I use for smtp and which doesn't work:

```
echo "$mail_content" | /usr/bin/mailx \
  --set=smtp-auth=login \
  --set=smtp-auth-user="user@domain.com" \
  --set=smtp-auth-password="some-pass" \
  --set=smtp="ssl0.ovh.net" \
  --set=smtp-use-starttls \
  --set=from="$from" \
  $to
```

Output:

```
mailx: <int>:: unknown keyword `smtp-auth'
```

I try a lot of variation of this command (found in stack or elsewhere), and when I use `-S` instead of `--set` I got the message `mailx: unrecognized option -S`

Comment: Try enclosing the smtp-auth value in quotes `--set=smtp-auth="login"` like all other key=values you're setting.